# Bitcoind zmqpubrawtx notification - Filter out mempool transactions

Tags: bitcoind, zeromq

Bitcoind's `zmqpubrawtx` seems to notify the subscriber of any transactions that have been accepted to the mempool or included in a block.

Is there any easy way to filter out the mined transactions so we're only left with new mempool transactions?

If not, is there any other way to subscribe to mempool transactions only?